# UserWarning: Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a pytorch lightning module like this:

```
class GraphLevelGNN(pl.LightningModule):


    def __init__(self,**model_kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # Saving hyperparameters
        self.save_hyperparameters()

        self.model = GraphGNNModel(**model_kwargs)
        self.loss_module = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() 
        

    def forward(self, data, mode="train"):
        x, edge_index, batch_idx = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
        x = self.model(x.cpu(), edge_index.cpu(), batch_idx.cpu())
        x = x.squeeze(dim=-1)
        
        if self.hparams.c_out == 1:
            preds = (x > 0).float().cpu()
            data.y = data.y.float().cpu()
        else:
            preds = x.argmax(dim=-1).cpu()

        loss = self.loss_module(x.cpu(), data.y.cpu())
        acc = (preds.cpu() == data.y.cpu()).sum().float() / preds.shape[0]
        f1 = f1_score(preds.cpu(),data.y.cpu())  ##change f1/precision and recall was just testing
        precision = precision_score(preds.cpu(),data.y.cpu())
        recall = recall_score(preds.cpu(),data.y.cpu())

        return loss, acc, f1,precision, recall,preds

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.SGD(self.parameters(),lr=0.1) # High lr because of small dataset and small model
        return optimizer

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, acc, _,_,_,_ = self.forward(batch, mode="train")
        self.log('train_loss', loss,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
        self.log('train_acc', acc,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, acc, _,_,_,_ = self.forward(batch, mode="val")
        self.log('val_acc', acc,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
        self.log('val_loss', loss,on_epoch=True,logger=True)

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss,acc, f1,precision, recall,preds = self.forward(batch, mode="test")
        self.log('test_acc', acc,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
        self.log('test_f1', f1,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
        self.log('test_precision', precision,on_epoch=True,logger=True)       
        self.log('test_recall', recall,on_epoch=True,logger=True)
```

When I run the code, I get a warning:

```
(train_fn pid=404034) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/data.py:99: UserWarning: Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we found is 127. To avoid any miscalculations, use `self.log(..., batch_size=batch_size)`.
```

I'm not clear, which function am I meant to add the extra `self.log` to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning means PyTorch Lightning has trouble inferring the batch size of your training perhaps because the batch contains different element types with varying amounts of elements inside them. To make sure it uses the correct `batch_size` for loss and metric computation. You can specify it yourself as described on the warning message. By setting the `batch_size` argument on each `log` call, *e.g.*

```
self.log('train_acc', acc, on_epoch=True, logger=True, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: Hi, I think there something wrong with the last batch if it not enough batch_size it's till consider batch_size length when calculation accuracy or loss. I recognize it when I notice the accuracy is not dividable

Comment: According to the [documentation page](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/api/lightning.pytorch.core.LightningModule.html#lightning.pytorch.core.LightningModule.log), "This will be directly inferred from the loaded batch", so it must be the batch size of the current batch. If you log on the last batch where the size is smaller than the nominal size, then you have to pass that number. This argument is only required when the size can't be inferred automatically from the batch object.